# Which hook for a warning message?

Tags: hooks, status-messages

Which Hook should I use to simply print a message if a configuration is not done yet?

The only idea i've got was hook_node_view, but maybe someone knows something better ?

Comment: What configuration?

Comment: Doesnt matter, i just want to check a if a variable is set, that i've defined by myself. And if its not set, i want to say to the admin "hey u, set the variable in this(link) admin interface", and the check should be done on every page the admin visits

Comment: @Sebastian it does matter, otherwise we can't tell you what hook to use ;)

Comment: *["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* Also, get a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally that's what [`hook_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) is for

> Check installation requirements **and do status reporting**.

Emphasis mine.

It's how modules declare that they are missing a required Javascript library, for example.

It hooks your module into the status report at /admin/reports/status.

Drupal doesn't have a mechanism for displaying messages in response to a requirement failure; so if you need to show something to the user, `hook_node_view()` makes as much sense as anything else IMO.

Actually that's not strictly true (I didn't read the docs properly)...`hook_requirements()` does already handle that in one way or another. From the docs relating to the 'runtime' phase:

> any requirement with a severity of REQUIREMENT_ERROR severity will result in a notice on the administration configuration page.

So if your users have access to the admin config page you *can* use this hook to automatically display them a message. But if the message needs to be on a different page, you'll have to take a different route with the advice in @FreeRadical's answer.

Comment: Thanks, and I started thinking that i am to dumb to ask questions after getting flamed by the guys above that post ...

Comment: They're not trying to flame (if you can take my word for it), they're just trying to get to the root of the issue as they don't feel there's enough info to go on. I disagree (I thought it was clear as day), but do make allowances for people misunderstanding...it does happen :)

Comment: @Clive actually `hook_node_view()` does not make sense if module in question have nothing to do with nodes, and admin who installed it will stay in admin area, not going to see any nodes because task he is about to do, task he needed module for, does not involve them. So I still think this question lacks a bit of information needed to choose hook that will actually get the message delivered when it's needed. and I honestly didn't meant to "flame" - why would I link to hook_requirements then?

Comment: @Mołot I'm (rightly or wrongly) making the assumption that the OP mentioning `hook_node_view()` inferred the need for the message on a node page. Ideally, every person that ever read anything written by anybody else on the internet would do so with a completely neutral perspective, and assume zero emotion (or maybe even default to positive)...but that ain't human nature :) We read something innocuous, and irrationally feel like we're under attack, and need to defend our position I've done it once already myself _today_. Got me chewing someone out for no reason, and then tail between legs ;)

Comment: Moral of the story (for everybody, not you) - assume everyone's being nice until you have definitive proof otherwise

Comment: @Clive If only OP would have answered "configuration about interacting with nodes" to my first question... I'm just very reluctant to assume anything. I deleted quite a bit of answers posted on bad assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check installation requirements and report on any failures *during installation* or any of the other phases where it is applicable, it is `hook_requirements()` - already adequately covered by Clive.

But if you just want to print a warning message to the user/admin about some tasks (such as setting some variables), e.g.:

```
drupal_set_message(t('You've selected X and Y. These are mutually exclusive.'), 'warning');
```

... you can call this function from more or less *anywhere* inside one of the functions in your module where you do some check and want to output a warning because the check indicates that something should be done before proceeding. It doesn't have to be a hook. But obviously the function containing the call need to be executed for the message to show. However, placing it inside the same function as the function that performs the check usually takes care of that.

For instance, if the message is used to tell the admin that his choces are mutually exclusive, I have it inside settings submit handler (e.g. `MYMODULE_admin_settings_submit`). since I usually do this type of sanity checks in the submit handler.

PS: Calling `drupal_set_message()` just appends the message to an array that is shown on the next page load.

Comment: I think OP already knows how to set a message, but he wasn't quite sure *where to call* `drupal_set_message` for desired effect.

Comment: Small note...`hook_requirements()` isn't just for installation requirements - it has several phases, one of which is 'runtime' (for runtime requirements as it suggests). If you look at the status report on an installed site, all of the green/yellow/red rows come from one implementation of `hook_requirements()` or another, using the 'runtime' phase

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I just wanted to refer the user to your answer for that angle. Hope it is more correct now.